# Java: Import error within single directory?

Tags: java, javac

I'm new to Java.

All of my source files (eg. TreeJPanel.java, Tree.java) are in a **single directory** called jview, with dependencies between them. When I try to compile with

```
javac jview/TreeJPanel.java
```

I get this:

```
jview/TreeJPanel.java:39: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Tree
location: class TreeJPanel
  protected Tree tree;
            ^
jview/TreeJPanel.java:41: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Tree
location: class TreeJPanel
  public Tree getTree() {
         ^
jview/TreeJPanel.java:45: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Tree
location: class TreeJPanel
  public void setTree(Tree tree) {
```

There's 15 similar errors. I thought I don't need explicit imports from within the same directory? What am I doing wrong? It is likely my question reveals a lack of conceptual understanding of Java - please feel free to point out. Thanks!

Comment: Try compiling all files at once: `javac jview/*.java`

Comment: IIRC, if you cd into jview and run `javac TreePanel.java`, the dependency resolution should work as expected. Keep in mind, though, that it's been years since I've compiled Java from the command line.

Comment: Same errors, only more in number.

Answer (score 0):

Was `Tree.java` first compiled into `Tree.class`? when `TreeJPanel.java` was trying to compile, it was searching for it.

Comment: I did not know this. Do all dependencies need to be in .class form before current compilation? I suspected that as possible cause. So now, should I manually go through the dependencies? Or is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling both files together:

```
      javac jview/Tree.java jview/TreeJPanel.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause for this is very simple just u should import the Tree Class into the TreeJpanel Class

Your code should look like this

```
import jview.Tree;

Class TreeJPanel { ....
```